# ArgumentException when calling StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync concurrently

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am getting ArgumentExceptions when there are multiple calls to Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync on different threads.  Here is a test that reproduces the issue:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ConcurrentGetFolderFromPath()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string localFolderPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
                //await Task.Yield();
                var folder = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(localFolderPath);
            });

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
Result StackTrace:  
    at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(String path)
    at PCLStorage.Test.FolderTests.<<ConcurrentGetFolderFromPath>b__53>d__55.MoveNext() in c:\git\pclstorage\test\PCLStorage.Test\FolderTests.cs:line 205
```

The test fails consistently for me when I run it by itself, but generally passes when I run it along with the rest of the [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) tests.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Are GetFolderFromPathAsync or any of the other APIs I'm using only supposed to be used from the UI thread?  Or is this possibly a bug in the WinRT storage APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the issue here is one of `Task.Run` and the way it handles `async delegates`. Basically, when you say:

```
Task.Run(async () => ...)
```

What it's returning to you is not the plain-jane `Task` you are expecting it to. It's returning that task *wrapped in another task*, i.e., a Task. So in order to get the task out that you're looking for (the one that retrieves the StorageFolder), you need to `await` the outer task. You can do this simply by changing when you add it to the `tasks` list:

```
tasks.Add(await task);
```

Now, there is a second issue. You're doing a bunch of reading from the same folder possibly all at the same time. This may cause some `AccessExceptions`. It may also not. I would just be careful when doing this.

I have had problems doing file read/write in unit tests in WinRT. Luckily, I am using Mvvm (through Mvvm Light) and have wrapped my local storage accessing inside of a `Controller`. What this has allowed me to do is to write a `LocalStorageController` just for Unit testing that allows me to do all of my IO to a file system in memory (basically a simple `Dictionary<string, byte[]>`). This does make testing complex file trees a bit more difficult, but you could also use a different data structure (such as an actual `Tree`) to model your file system.

Anyway, I hope this helps. I apologize that it was so long after you asked it, though. Happy coding!